# How to access a variable inside a function placed inside componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

I have one variable declared inside componentDidMount and one function it is also inside componentDidMount. I am trying to access that variable inside the function but ending up with an error.

I am using this variable through this component. I am trying to assigning the value to this variable but it is not accessible from the function. Please see the code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.weatherData = new Object();
    function success(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lon = position.coords.longitude;
     fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&appid=4d0cedb0b2ae0c240bf3c08ab455915e")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.weatherData.data = data);
      console.log(this.weatherData);
    }

    function error(err) {
      alert(err.code);
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }
```

The data should be assigned to the weatherData object. I am updating this object later on in the application when the user changes location to other city. The error I am getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weatherData' of undefined at success

and

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'weatherData' of undefined

Comment: Can you show how you define functions where you use `weatherData` ?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Well, I am using that weatherData in the same component but in other methods. I just need to know how can i access weatherData inside the success function. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a fat arrow function so that `this` references the correct object. So basically:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.weatherData = new Object();

  const success = (position) => {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    fetch("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&appid=4d0cedb0b2ae0c240bf3c08ab455915e")
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => this.weatherData.data = data);
    console.log(this.weatherData);
  }

  const error = (err) => {
   alert(err.code);
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Note that because of the async nature of `fetch` your console.log will execute before you re-assign `weatherData`. It won't print what you are probably expecting. You should move your console log inside the `then`, if you want to see its value.